# how to convert List[java.util.Map] to List[Map]

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-java-interop

how to convert List[java.util.Map] to List[Map] in scala?

oldList:

```
List[java.util.Map[String,String]]
```

wantedList:

```
List[Map[String,String]]
```

should i new a List[Map] and loop the oldList ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use converter methods in Scala collection package. and this is a sample to demonstrate how to convert:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

oldList: List[java.util.Map[String,String]]

wantedList= oldList.asScala
```

**Edited:**

as Vladimir Matveev mentioned

```
wantedList=oldList.map(_.asScala)
```

Comment: The overall direction (usage of `JavaConverters`) is correct, but you have to map through the list with `asScala`, not just call this method on the list: `oldList.map(_.asScala)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `scala.collection.JavaConversions` static methods. This one adds implicit conversions from standard Java collections and allows you to perform things like this (let's assume we have already opened REPL and imported `scala.collection.JavaConversions._`):

```
scala > x
res1: java.util.HashMap[String,String] = {1=2}

scala> x.toMap
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(1 -> 2)
```

You could solve your particular problem as following:

```
res5: list: List[java.util.HashMap[String, String]] = ()
scala > list.map(e => e.toMap)
res6: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = ()
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaConverters were deprecated since Scala 2.9.0 and removed in [Scala 2.11-M1](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/JavaConverters.scala) **you should not use them**. Instead there is a package `scala.collection.convert` with a module `WrapAsScala`. It has an implicit convertion `dictionaryAsScalaMap`

Comment: There were a few members of `JavaConverters` that were deprecated but `JavaConverters` in general is *not* deprecated.

Comment: @sourcedelica [JavaConverters](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/collection/JavaConverters.scala) as you can see all members were deprecated

Comment: Those internal members were deprecated but everything that it inherits from `DecorateAsJava` and `DecorateAsScala` were not.  The `JavaConverters` `object` itself was not, and `import JavaConverters._` still works as it used to. Eg. you can do `jmap.asScala`.

Comment: @sourcedelica That was done for migration purposes and backward compatibility in [Scala 2.11-M1](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/JavaConverters.scala) they were removed.

Comment: Here is the nightly API docs: http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters$